# Where does rsync copy a file if I don't specify the remote path?

Tags: rsync, file-copy

When using `rsync` to copy files over the network, I give a path so that `rsync` will know where to put the file on the remote server.

`rsync -av /home/ME/myfile user@remoteserver:/home/ME/`

If I leave off the remote path, where will `rsync` put the file? Eg:

`rsync -av /home/ME/myfile user@remoteserver`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
rsync -av /home/ME/myfile user@remoteserver
```

This command will not send the file to your remote server, it will just make a duplicate of the `/home/me/myfile` in your current working directory and the name of the file will be called `user@remoteserver`.

Just like when you want to create a backup of a file before editing it with `cp`, you do

```
cp -a /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.org
```

Answer (score 6):

Your example of

`rsync -av /home/ME/myfile user@remoteserver`

has left off the colon.  Without that, it assumes the file is local.

If you instead had

`rsync -av /home/ME/myfile user@remoteserver:`

Then it would make a remote copy.  In this case the location is relative to the home directory of the user.  With no relative path given, the file will appear in that directory.

```
$ rsync -v myfile user@remoteserver:
user@remoteservers's password: 
myfile

sent 619 bytes  received 35 bytes  145.33 bytes/sec
total size is 529  speedup is 0.81
$ ssh user@remoteserver "ls ./myfile"
user@remoteserver's password: 
./myfile
```